# How to check if user is confirmed in AWS Amplify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

I have a check to see if the user is already in the DB, which is `if (e.name === 'UsernameExistsException') {...`

I tried this check to see if it would return `true` or `false`, but no luck: `console.log(await Auth.verifiedContact(this.state.email));`

How can I check if that user is confirmed or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out within minutes after posting the question. Here is the check I could use for a user not being confirmed:

`if (e.name === 'UserNotConfirmedException)'`